# Submitting data to Soap Server with PHP

Tags: php, wsdl, soap-client

I am unable to pass the header to the WSDL for credencials:

this is the code:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://www.em-sender.com/ws/InwiseWebServices.asmx?WSDL");
$header = array('user'=>'user1','pass'=>'pass1');
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader("https://www.em-sender.com/ws/InwiseWebServices.asmx?WSDL",'SecHeader',$header));
$res = $soapClient->__call("Recipients_checkUnsubscribed", array('email'=> 'test@test.com'));
var_dump($res);
```

I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] Please
>   provide security header in...

this is the WSDL description: https://www.em-sender.com/ws/InwiseWebServices.asmx?op=Recipients_checkUnsubscribed

or see here:

```
POST /ws/InwiseWebServices.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.em-sender.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Header>
    <SecHeader xmlns="http://www.inwise.com/schemas">
      <username>string</username>
      <pass>string</pass>
    </SecHeader>
    <AuthIdentifier xmlns="http://www.inwise.com/schemas">
      <identifier>string</identifier>
    </AuthIdentifier>
  </soap12:Header>
  <soap12:Body>
    <Recipients_checkUnsubscribed xmlns="http://www.inwise.com/schemas">
      <email>string</email>
    </Recipients_checkUnsubscribed>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Recipients_checkUnsubscribedResponse xmlns="http://www.inwise.com/schemas">
      <Recipients_checkUnsubscribedResult>boolean</Recipients_checkUnsubscribedResult>
    </Recipients_checkUnsubscribedResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

**Edit**

This is the sent string:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.inwise.com/schemas" xmlns:ns2="https://www.em-sender.com/ws/InwiseWebServices.asmx?WSDL"> 
<SOAP-ENV:Header> 
    <ns2:SecHeader> 
        <item> 
            <key>user</key> 
            <value>user1</value> 
        </item> 
        <item> 
            <key>pass</key> 
            <value>pass1</value> 
        </item> 
    </ns2:SecHeader> 
</SOAP-ENV:Header> 
<SOAP-ENV:Body> 
    <ns1:Recipients_checkUnsubscribed/> 
</SOAP-ENV:Body> 
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with the request string you are sending to the soap server? You can get this by calling __getLastRequest() on the client.

Comment: @Kees Schepers - I can't because it cant try catch it, and I dont have xdebug_disable() available, so the script is ending. thanks

Comment: With the following you should see some more information: http://pastebin.com/NcJbR641 try that and compare your request with the one from the manual.

Comment: Isn't SecHeader in ns1 and not ns2?

Comment: Also I'm not sure if multiple user/passwords are supported within <item>

Comment: @powtac,@Kees Schepers -  I don't understand, can you please try to fix the code in an answer body? thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reviewed your SOAP request, and if you exactly compare you can see two problems:

1. The key/value pairs weren't okay (should be username and pass)
2. The namespace of the soapheader was incorrect.

If I try the following then I get a error message telling my credentials are invalid which makes sense because I just filled in something. I won't get the security header fault anymore.

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://www.em-sender.com/ws/InwiseWebServices.asmx?WSDL", array('trace' => true));
$header = new SoapVar(array('username' => 'user', 'pass' => 'password'), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader("http://www.inwise.com/schemas",'SecHeader',$header));

try {
    $res = $soapClient->Recipients_checkUnsubscribed('test@test.com');
    var_dump($res);
} catch(SoapFault $fault) {
    var_dump($soapClient->__getLastRequest());
    var_dump($fault->getMessage());
}
```